# How to Create A Command Line Command

Tags: bash, unix

So I recently installed Cassandra on OSX. I have it in my /usr/bin/ file. In order to start cassandra though I have to be in the /usr/bin/apache-cassandra-1.2.1/ directory (or specify the path). How can I create a command so that no matter where I am in the system I can just type 'cassandra' and have it run Cassandra?

Comment: You have to add `/usr/bin/apache-cassandra-1.2.1/` to your `$PATH`

Comment: You can also add this line to `~/.bashrc` : `alias cassandra='/usr/bin/apache-cassandra-1.2.1/cassandra'.

Comment: Awesome, this worked great. Thanks so much for the help. Trying to get over this learning curve!